# Java ArrayList indexOf generic type

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, generic-collections

**ArrayList** described as

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

And most of main methods work with *E* generic type (**get**, **set**, **add**, **addAll** etc).

But methods **contains**, **indexOf**, **lastIndexOf** and **remove** take the *Object* type as parameter - is this only because of inner use or *Object.equals()* or anything else?

Comment: Are the answers to the linked question clear enough or should I elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collection types only use their generic type `E` in cases where it *must* match in order for the operation to be legal. If you have a list of strings then clearly something like `add` can only make sense when passed a string.

But for operations like `contains` it's different - it is perfectly legal to *ask* whether a list of strings contains a particular `Integer`, for example. The answer will always be no, but that doesn't make it an error to ask the question.

Comment: this explanation should have added into ArrayLists' javadoc, thanks! =)

Answer (score 3):

From the Java 7 API for [`ArrayList#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

> `public boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns `true` if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if this list contains at least
>   one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Looking at this, it's saying that the comparison to determine whether `o` is a member of the list depends upon `o`'s implementation of the `equals()` method. By specify the parameter type as `Object`, we can put the responsibility for determining equality on the input object's class, rather than `E`, the type parameter of the list.

Answer (score 2):

That is because contains, lastIndexOf, remove etc. methods need to check for the equality of objects before performing corresponding actions, which done by using equals method. And equal method comes from object class which should be overridden by generic type E object.
On the contarary to this get, set, add etc methods do not need any comparision.